# Python nested function is not equal to itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, nested

This simple Python code gets "False".

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        return 0
    return bar
print(foo() == foo())
```

When I request

```
print(foo(),foo())
```

I get

```
<function foo.<locals>.bar at 0x03A0BC40> <function foo.<locals>.bar at 0x03C850B8>
```

So does Python store the result of the bar function every time in the new memory slot? I'd be happy if someone explain how it works behind the scene and possibly how this code can be a little bit modified to get "True" (which still seems logical to me!).

Comment: Each invocation creates a new function object, **that is the whole point of defining a function inside another*

Answer (score 1):

Each `def` statement defines a new function. The same name and body doesn't really matter. You're basically doing something like this:

```
def foo():
    pass

old_foo = foo

def foo():
    pass

assert old_foo == foo # will fail
```

Comment: But if I try with only one def foo() of your version of the code (which would be more close to the one I provided in the question), I get True!

Answer (score 0):

`bar` is locally defined within `foo` the same way a local variable would be each time you call the `foo()`.

As you can see by the defult `__repr__`, they have different memory addresses, and since `bar` does not implement `__eq__`, the two instances of `bar` will not be equal.